# Spring Integration - FtpInboundFileSynchronizer Comparator configuration with DSL

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Spring Integration's `FtpInboundFileSynchronizer` allows for the setting of a `Comparator<FTPFile>` to allow ordering of the downloads. The documentation says:

> Starting with version 5.1, the synchronizer can be provided with a Comparator. This is useful when restricting the number of files fetched with maxFetchSize.

This is fine for @Bean configuration:

```
 @Bean
 public FtpInboundFileSynchronizer ftpInboundFileSynchronizer(...)
        FtpInboundFileSynchronizer synchronizer = new FtpInboundFileSynchronizer(sessionFactory);
        ...
        synchronizer.setComparator(comparator);
        return synchronizer;
    }
```

But if I want to programatically assemble flows, the Java DSL is encouraged.

```
 StandardIntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows
                .from(Ftp.inboundAdapter(ftpFileSessionFactory, comparator)
                                .maxFetchSize(1)
    ...
```

The comparator in the `Ftp.inboundAdapter(...)` factory method is only for the comparison of files locally, after they have been downloaded. There are configuration settings that get passed to the synchronizer here (like remote directory, timestamp, etc.). But there is no setting for the synchronizer equivalent to setting it above.

Solution attempt:

The alternative is to create the synchronizer as non-bean, create the `FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource` in a similar way, and use `IntegrationFlows.from(source)` to assemble the synchronizer results in a runtime exception when the flow is registered with the flow context:

```
Creating EvaluationContext with no beanFactory
java.lang.RuntimeException: No beanFactory
    at org.springframework.integration.expression.ExpressionUtils.createStandardEvaluationContext(ExpressionUtils.java:90) ~[spring-integration-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:299) ~[spring-integration-file-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
```

That makes sense; the `FtpInboundFileSynchronizer` is not supposed to be constructed outside of a context. (Though this does appear to work.) But how, in that case, can I dynamically assemble ftp integration flows with a synchronizer configured with a `Comparator<FTPFile>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like we have missed to expose that `remoteComparator` option in DSL.

Feel free to raise a GH issue or even contribute a fix: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues

As a workaround for dynamic flows, I really would suggest to go a separate `FtpInboundFileSynchronizer` and `FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource` and then use the mentioned `IntegrationFlows.from(source)`. What you probably miss in your configuration is this API:

```
    /**
     * Add an object which will be registered as an {@link IntegrationFlow} dependant bean in the
     * application context. Usually it is some support component, which needs an application context.
     * For example dynamically created connection factories or header mappers for AMQP, JMS, TCP etc.
     * @param bean an additional arbitrary bean to register into the application context.
     * @return the current builder instance
     */
    IntegrationFlowRegistrationBuilder addBean(Object bean);
```

I mean that `FtpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource` is OK to pass to the `from()` as a  is, but `synchronizer` has to be added as an extra bean for registration.

Another more fancy way is to consider to use a new feature called DSL extensions: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-extensions

So, you can extend that `FtpInboundChannelAdapterSpec` to provide a missed option to configure for an internal `synchronizer`.

Comment: Thanks Artem. I will take a look at contributing a fix if I manage to get my head around things!

I did try the `addBean` method - it didn't seem to make a difference, and I'm guessing it's because it's too late for Spring methods to add a BeanFactory to the `FtpInboundFileSynchronizer `. 

In the end I noted that it's only a Warn rather than an Error, so I'm able to ignore it for now.

Comment: See the mentioned GH issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3372